# Angular js showing {{variable}} on mobile

Tags: angularjs, mobile

I've built the webapp based on angularjs at http://jesco-online-academy.be

Everything's ok on desktop but if you'll visit it on mobile you'll see all the

```
{{some.variable}}
```

I can't figure out where the problem is.

Anybody faced this?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'errorMobile' of undefined
at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:87)
at invoke (angular.js:2880)
at Object.instantiate (angular.js:2890)
at $get (angular.js:5178)
at update (angular.js:15668)
at Object.$get.Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:8935)
at angular.js:7960
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:7303)
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:7303)
at angular.js:7340
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6173
$get @ angular.js:5219$get.Scope.$broadcast @ angular.js:8937
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:7960
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback @angular.js:7303
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback @ angular.js:7303
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:7340
$get.Scope.$eval @ angular.js:8685
$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:8548
$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:8771
done @ angular.js:10004
completeRequest @ angular.js:10180
xhr.onreadystatechange @ angular.js:10144
```

Comment: can you show error page and call stack?

Comment: btw, your bootstrap don't have jQuery that it need

Comment: @Sushant Can't paste images, visit the link. Added the call stack

Answer (score 0):

[image: These are the errors that're coming up on the console]

These are the errors that're coming up on the console

Try including jQuery. Else, try adding the Bootstrap include **after** the angularJS include, as angular already has jQuery Lite

Comment: Tried both - didn't help